# How to create two plot areas with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to plot several values across the same time series.  However, I'd like to split them up into separate plot areas.  Ideally, it would be a single Y axis and multiple X axis.    I don't just want a secondary axis as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/9/).

I realize I could just create two charts, but then the time series might not line up perfectly well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one x-axis versus multiple y-axes. I think the example is self explanatory: http://jsfiddle.net/unqmP/

Revision: Adding the JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function(data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length;

        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ])
        }

        // set the allowed units for data grouping
        var groupingUnits = [[
            'week',                         // unit name
            [1]                             // allowed multiples
        ], [
            'month',
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]];

        // create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                alignTicks: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Historical'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: 200,
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: 300,
                height: 100,
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'spline',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'spline',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In highcharts instead of highstock (Same approach as above): http://jsfiddle.net/markwatson/D7rBR/